# Uniform Continuity of $x \sin x$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

How does one go about proving that the function $x \sin x$ is not uniformly continuous on the set of real numbers ?

Any method that uses the sequential criterion for discontinuity would be preferred.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sequential continuity has nothing to do with this, as $x \sin x$ *is* continuous, just not uniformly so.

Comment: Given $\delta>0$, consider the function's values at points of the form $2n\pi$ and $2n\pi+\delta$ for integer $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elaborating on David Mitra's Comment:

From continuity of $x\sin(x)$, you have that 
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \forall y, \exists \delta: |x-y|<\delta\implies |x\sin(x)-y\sin(y)|<\epsilon$$

But define $$p=x+2n\pi;\;\;\;q=p=y+2n\pi$$

Then you have
$|p-q|<\delta$ but $$|(x+2n\pi)\sin(x+2n\pi)-(y+2n\pi)\sin(y+2n\pi)|$$ $$=|(x\sin(x)-y\sin(y))+2n\pi(\sin(x)-\sin(y))|>\epsilon$$
for sufficiently large $n$. An undesirable result for uniform continuity.

Comment: How does p=q, when you have x != y?

Answer (score 20):

Let $f(x)=x\sin x$ and $x_n=\pi n$ and $y_n=\pi n+\frac{1}{n}$
 then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}( y_n-x_n)=0$ and

$f(y_n)-f(x_n)=(\pi n+\frac{1}{n})\sin(\pi n+\frac{1}{n})-\pi n\sin(n\pi)=_{n\longrightarrow\infty} \pi(-1)^n+o(1)\not \to 0$

Answer (score 5):

Since $x\sin(x)$ is continuous, we won't be able to show discontinuity. It is the uniformity of the continuity that we have to consider. $f$ is uniform continuous if and only if

> $$\forall\epsilon\gt0,\exists\,\delta\gt0:\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},|x-y|\le\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\le\epsilon\tag{1}$$

The inverse of $(1)$ is

> $$\exists\,\epsilon\gt0:\forall\,\delta\gt0,\exists\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}:|x-y|\le\delta\wedge\,|f(x)-f(y)|\gt\epsilon\tag{2}$$

We can take $\epsilon=1$. Given $\delta>0$, let $\eta=\min(\delta,\pi/2)$ and $x=2\pi\left\lceil\dfrac1{2\pi\sin(\eta)}\right\rceil$ and $y=x+\eta$. Then $f(x)=0$ and
$$
\begin{align}
f(y)
&=(x+\eta)\sin(x+\eta)\\
&=(x+\eta)\sin(\eta)\\
&\gt x\sin(\eta)\\
&\ge1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Will $sin (x \sin x)$ be uniformly Continuous or not???????????@robjohn♦

Comment: @sani: we have shown that for any $\delta\gt0$, no matter how small, we can find two points, $x$ and $y$, so that $|x-y|\le\delta$, yet $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge1$. Thus, we have satisfied $(2)$, which is the inverse of $(1)$. So, *no*, $x\sin(x)$ is *not* uniformly continuous.

Comment: No no I am talking about the function sin(xsinx)....Will this be uniformly continuous?

Comment: Oh, that is a completely different question.  I thought with all the questions marks, the confusion was about the question here. If you have a *new* question, you can just post that question and reference this question. However, using exactly the same argument above, and the exact same $x$ and $y$, we have shown that for any $\delta\gt0$, we can find two points $|x-y|\le\delta$ so that $|\sin(x\sin(x))-\sin(y\sin(y))|\ge\sin(1)$.

Comment: Can u plz give that specific sequence for which this happens??

Comment: @sani: what property would you like the sequence to have? You could take $\delta=\frac1n$ and plug it into the formula in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\ge1}$ be any two sequences from the domain such that $x_n=2n^2\pi+\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $y_n=2n^2\pi$.

Now,

\begin{align}\left\lvert x_n\sin x_n-y_n\sin y_n\right\rvert&=\left\lvert \left(2n^2\pi+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\sin \left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right\rvert\\&=\left(2n^2\pi+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\sin \left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\\&>2n^2\pi\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\\&>1\end{align} [for all sufficiently large $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449701/prove-that-the-sequence-left-n2-sin-left-frac1n-right-right-n-ge-1).