# Prove that the sequence $\left( n^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)_{n\ge 1}$ is unbounded above

Tags: real-analysis

> Without using the series expansion of $\sin x$ how can we show that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ where $x_n=n^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded above?

I have tried quite sometime to prove this but couldn't get anything. Any help will be appreciated. It will be better if only **hint** is given (if given at all).

Comment: Hint: Recall that $(\sin x)/x$ has limit $1$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
allows you to say that there exists $\delta>0$ such that, if $0<|x|<\delta$, we have
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x}>\frac{1}{2}
$$
(take $\varepsilon=1/2$ in the definition of limit. Thus, if $n>\frac{1}{\delta}$, we have
$$
n\sin\frac{1}{n}=\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}>\frac{1}{2}
$$
and so
$$
n^2\sin\frac{1}{n}>\frac{n}{2}
$$
Therefore no $M>0$ can be an upper bound for the sequence, because it suffices to take $n>\max\{1/\delta,2M\}$ to get that
$$
n^2\sin\frac{1}{n}>\frac{n}{2}>\frac{2M}{2}=M
$$

Answer (score 0):

With equivalents:
$$n^2\sin\frac1n\sim_\infty n^2\cdot\frac1n=n,$$
which is not bounded from above.

Answer (score 0):

Following André Nicolas' hint: $$x_{n}=n^{2} \sin \frac{1}{n}= n \frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
And the fraction tends to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know L'hopital's rule, you can compute the equivalent limit, $\lim_{t \to 0} (\sin t)/t^2$ after the substitution $t = 1/n$.